# confusing String substring syntax after Xcode 7.0.1 upgrade

Tags: ios, swift

after upgrade to Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) syntax is confusing and cannot work out correct syntax.  I have a String extension to extract substring.  After upgrade, Xcode rejects old syntax, and any new changes I make to it.  Are the Apple Gods throwing their weight around ?

```
extension String {

func substring(start: Int, end: Int) -> String{
    return self.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(self.startIndex, start), end: advance(self.startIndex, end)))
}
```

[image: Xcode wants advancedBy, but rejects it when I try to do so]

Comment: you just have to use new syntax advancedBy startIndex.advancedBy(start)

Comment: tried any syntax under the sun. it keeps telling me something else is wrong.  and about being a duplicate: I cannot find any other post that is equal to this....

Comment: Be aware that if you input an invalid range it will crash your app

Comment: Actually the error message says exactly what to to. The callee is `advancedBy()` and the caller is the index.

Comment: Sorry, but I found documentation confusing and perhaps in many ways contradicting. Xcode upgrade was released on 28 sep. Trying to do the auto changes via built-in syntax fixer to latest swift code only destroys the entire project.... Apple documentation does not match latest release ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
extension String {
    func substring(start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
        return substringWithRange(startIndex.advancedBy(start)...startIndex.advancedBy(end))
    }
}
```

Comment: seems to have accepted syntax... at last. Thank you